# Katalon cannot send request

Tags: session-cookies, katalon-studio, httpcookie, katalon

When I send a request, it always returns status code 200 but the response is direct to the login page and not the value of my request.

Here is my manual script:

```
String mycookie = GlobalVariable.myToken
String mycsrf = GlobalVariable.mycsrf
    
String callfullurl = server+thepathURR+param
String authHeader = ""

TestObjectProperty header1 = new TestObjectProperty("Cookie", ConditionType.EQUALS, mycookie)
TestObjectProperty header2 = new TestObjectProperty("Content-Type", ConditionType.EQUALS, "application/json")
TestObjectProperty header3 = new TestObjectProperty("Accept", ConditionType.EQUALS, "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9")
ArrayList defaultHeaders = Arrays.asList(header1, header2, header3)

RequestObject ro = new RequestObject()
ro.setRestUrl(callfullurl)
ro.setFollowRedirects(true)
ro.setHttpHeaderProperties(defaultHeaders)
ro.setRestRequestMethod(method)

def respObj = WS.sendRequest(ro)

'Get the response of requested Ajax'
String response = respObj.getResponseText()

'Get the response status'
def chkcode = respObj.getStatusCode()
```

[image]

[image]